# Is there a benefit to using the "eraser" side of a Wacom tablet?

Tags: drawing-tablet, painting, wacom

Wacom Intuous and Intuous Pro has an eraser side on it that at least in Photoshop defaults to... the eraser. I'm not sure however, and couldn't find much about that side of the stylus. Not sure if there's any benefit, otherwise its just as fast, if not faster, for me to tap the <kbd>E</kbd> with my off hand.

Is it just personal preference or is there some technical benefit (like different pressure sensitivity, or tilt control, or something) to using the Eraser side of a Wacom?

Comment: I feel it is a little dumb to rotate the pen. At the end it is just another kind of brush, one that deletes. so I never rotate it... I do not want to scrach my pen either.

Comment: In over a decade of using a Wacom tablet... I have *never* used the eraser end of the stylus.

Comment: I discovered this back in 2001 or so, but I don't think I've ever used a second brush/eraser in my everyday use. I wonder if there's a way to make it scroll or zoom somehow. Flip the pen, move stuff around, flip it back, get to work.

Comment: I newer understood why are people using real life logic (like position of eraser on a real pen) in digital world! I am always frustrated by erasing options in photoshop. Eraser should be by default a press-release button. You know, that side button that every stylus has? Universe wants it! Erase and continue moving on, no tool change (unless you want it), no pen flipping (I mean, come on).

Comment: You can actually configure it to do this. @Helen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always assumed it was for familiarity + perhaps to further enable people to use the tablet without a keyboard. When you first try out a drawing tablet, it seems like it makes sense to have it, but I've personally never used it. It's so tedious

<sub><sup>Wacom even has an option to set one of the stylus buttons as the eraser. I've found that to lag a bit, so I usually just e and b. By lag I mean that sometimes the last stroke ends up being a normal brush stroke. The eraser tip does work just fine</sup></sub>

Maybe the biggest benefit of using the eraser tip would be how Photoshop handles it. Photoshop retains the same brush when you are using brush tool and switch to the eraser side of the stylus. *If you toggle the tools with `e` and `b`, you may have different style brushes in each tool.*

<sub><sup>I do like to keep my eraser tool separated from the brush tool. If I'm using some sort of artistic scatter brush and then if I want to erase, I most likely will not want to use the scatter brush to do it.</sup></sub>

---

Not all applications do it the same way as PS. Some applications may just kind of switch to the eraser tool when you are using the eraser tip <sup><sub>( This could be outdated information. )</sub></sup>

Comment: On my windows machine I have a AHK script that toggles between pressing keys `e` and `b`, which enables you to switch between eraser tool and brush tool. If you want to try it, here's the script file: [toggle (Eraser-Brush).ahk](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e20vwmpve4rnqai/toggle%20%28Eraser-Brush%29.ahk?dl=0). You need to set one of the stylus buttons to trigger a`keystroke`:  `Alt+Shift+<` and double click the script to open it. Once you've done that, one of the stylus buttons should toggle between `e` and `b`. @Ryan, this script should look familiar to you.

Answer (score 3):

There's is no difference from Photoshops view. Technically its a similar albeit differently shaped nib, that is always attached to eraser. The different shape has different physics, but other then that form software's point of view its the same.

The tablet user may not have a second hand free, for example because they have leaned back and the keyboard is too far away. In this case it could be convenient. I think that in general its really hard to draw conclusions from your own preference.

For example: I see no big benefit of using a 3D mouse. But some users swear by it.

Same applies here its really hard to estimate whether or not somebody preference is actually useful or not. Personally i do not use the eraser much in PS. But I do use it quite much in sketchbook pro.